# How to disable .change function when the page loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

In my `$(document).ready()` function I have a `.change` event bound to a set or radio buttons. If there is an error on the form the user submits, however, the page will re-load with the values selected by the user. This is causing the radio button `.change` function to fire every time the page loads, which I do not want it to do. How would I disable this?

**EDIT**

Here's the full function, didn't post prior due to the fact it's a hot mess in the middle right now and was trying to keep the readability of this post in mind.

FYI - If there has been an error after the user submits the form then I need the page to load the form as it was when the user hit the submit button. Since we display a certain set of `div` and `span` elements based on the radio button selection, I used the `trigger('change')` method. Is there any way to detect if the operation is occurring during a page load?

```
    $('input[name=TransactionType]').change(function (e) {
        //Clear any messages from previous transaction
        $('.error').text('');
        $('.success').text('');

        //Display fieldset Submit and Cancel(back to search) link
        $('#PageDirection').show();
        $('#AgentInformation').show();

        //Display input fields
        var radioValue = $(this);

        if (radioValue.attr('id') == "Enroll" || (radioValue.attr('id') == "ModT")) {
            //Enable and disable input boxes
            $('span').not('#AllInput').hide();
            $('#AllInput').show();
            $('#PayFrequency').show();
            $('#refNumberInput').show();

            //Set tooltips
            $('#AccountType').removeAttr("title");
            if (radioValue.attr('id') == "Enroll") {
                $('#PaymentFrequency').removeAttr("title");
                $('.req').show();
                $('#refNumberInput').show();
                $('#enrollNote').show();
            } else {
                $('#PaperStatement').show();
                $('#PaymentFrequency').attr("title", "Select the frequency to pay the distributor");
                $('#refNumberInput').show();
            }
        } else if (radioValue.attr('id') == "New") {
            $('span').not('#NewMessage').hide();
            $('#NewMessage').show();
            $('.req').show();
            $('#refNumberInput').show();

        } else if (radioValue.attr('id') == "ModA") {
            $('#AllInput').show();
            $('#AgentIdSpan').show();
            $('.req').show();
            $('#UnenrollMessage').hide();
            $('#NewMessage').hide();
            $('#PayFrequency').hide();
            $('#PaperStatement').hide();
            $('#refNumberInput').show();
            $('#AgentId').attr("title", "Enter the Agent ID to be modified");

        } else if (radioValue.attr('id') == "Clone") {
            $('span').not('#AgentIdSpan').hide();
            $('#AgentIdSpan').show();
            $('.req').show();
            $('#AgentId').attr("title", "Clone EFT onto this Agent ID");

        } else if (radioValue.attr('id') == "Unenroll") {
            $('span').not('#UnenrollMessage').hide();
            $('#UnenrollMessage').show();
            $('.req').show();
            $('#refNumberInput').show();

        }

        if (radioValue.attr('id') != "Clone") {
            $('.alwaysReq').show();
        };
    }).filter(':checked').trigger('change');
```

Comment: how are you changing radio buttons on page load? what's the HTML form look like?

Comment: the change function doesn't fire everytime the page loads unless you call trigger(). It just gets registered & fires on change.

Comment: The change function doesn't even fire if you change the state programatically, you have to physically change the radio, or call trigger().

Comment: @adeneo, He's probably having this issue because of the browser's autocompletion feature, which triggers change events.

Comment: I am calling trigger, my fault. Copied a portion of this function because there's a whole bunch of code in the middle and forgot to paste this to the end.

Comment: Posted the whole method. (now you can see what I mean ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you do not care about auto-completion you could put `autocomplete="off"` on the `form`. You could also compare the current field value with it's [defaultValue](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement) to see if it was automatically populated by the browser.

Answer (score 0):

you can use "on" or "delegate" inside the jquery ready function.
like this:

```
   $(document).delegate("input[name=TransactionType]","change", function(){
        $('.error').text('');
        $('.success').text('');
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.ready` won't usually call the change the function. It will only get called if you manually change the checkbox, or the same event influenced by some other function, but not in `document.ready`.

Please remove the `.trigger('change')` method as it would trigger the change method on `document.ready`

Comment: Unfortunately if the user enters an error, the form need to reload exactly as it did when the user hit submit. Since we use the `.change` event to display a certain set of `divs` and `spans`, I (think) I need to use the `.trigger` method.